# How to have Sonar Runner running when sources are on another server?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm a bit lost right now.

I managed to install sonar 3.5 on a Windows server 2008 and have it working with SQL server 2008.
I can access the dashboard and tables were created in the database.
This is the "sonar server".

The thing is I have my sources on another server, the "source server".
So I create a "project-properties" file alongside my `.sln` file.

Now I'll need to run the command

```
$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/bin/sonar-runner
```

but really don't see how to do it.

First i'd like to know if it's possible.
And if it is, how to?

If you need more information let me know, I'll provide it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly try the following:

1. Edit the sonar-runner so it points to the Sonar server, depending your firewall setting, you could try the sonar.host.url.
2. cd to the dir where the sonar-runner.properties
3. run the sonar-runner
4. fix any errors.

See also: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner

Comment: Hey Henry,  Thanks a lot. This : "Edit the sonar-runner so it points to the Sonar server" made me realize sonar_runner doesn't have to be on the sonar server but on the server where the sources are. Don't know why i didn't see it. Bye